# hide time gaps between points of line chart

Tags: echarts

How can I hide the time gap between two data points of a line chart when there are no values between them?

For example, 3 points:

- first point: time: friday, value: 2
- no points between friday and monday (should **not** be shown with a straight line)
- second point: time: monday, value: 4

I have tried it with

```
series: {
connectNulls: fals,
}
```

Did not work. Is there a other property for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Do not show datapoints**

Use `null` as value:

```
series: {
    data: [5, 2, null, null, 4, 5]
}
```

You do not need to use `connectNulls`.

[image]

---

**Do not show x axis ticks**

When you want to hide the x axis ticks for empty datapoints, switch your x axis to `type: category`, and exclude those values. Be sure to exclude them from your series as well.

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    data: ['thursday', 'friday', 'monday', 'tuesday']
},
series: {
    data: [5, 2, 4, 5]
}
```

[image]

Comment: But how can I hide these times (saturday and sunday) from the chart when there are no values betwen two points?

Comment: In that case, modify the `xAxis`, not the `series`. When using `type: 'time', there is not much you can do: the xAxis is generated by eCharts. You can however switch to `type: 'category', and then manually create your xAxis, in that case, you can just exclude empty days.

Comment: Thanks. However, category is not a good fit for my use case. Imagine time series lies between a day and there are gaps between a few hours. Category does not fit well.

Comment: It is not as bad as you think. I use eCharts a lot, and only use `type: category`, even for time based data. You should use unix timestamps, and display them correctly in your chart's axis with [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/). You can use a formatter like this: `xAxis: {data: myFunction(myDataset)}`.

Comment: note: when you insert nulls in your data it will also show up in the tooltip-window and when you export the data.